# Adding new field to each JSON Object

Tags: json

I am currently doing a project and I have a huge json list with schools in my country I would like to add one more field to each object, is there any website to do this, without typing it manually?

Comment: You have to post an example what do you have now and an example what do you want if you really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this.

First, I am assuming you are dealing with what is known as a `json array` which looks like this

```
[{name:"John", age:31, city:"New York"},
{name:"Jim", age:27, city:"London"},
{name:"Jeff", age:80, city:"Dublin"}]
```

You could simply use a program such as Notepad++ & do a search/replace `Ctrl+h`.

Find what: `}`

Replace with: `, mynewfield: ""}`

This method will replace all instances of an ending curly bracket (end of a json object) with a new field & value of your choice. So essentially, its just appending a new field for each object.

An alternative way that is also very useful when dealing with large data is with "regular expressions" (or regex expressions). The use case here for using a regex expression could be if you didn't want to add your new field to the end of each object but, somewhere in the middle (like before/after age).

In the case, you could use

Find what: `(?<=,)(.*)(?=age)` (or `(?<=,)(.*)(?=city)`)

Replace with:  `mynewfield: "",`

NOTE: For regex expressions you must have them enabled under the "Search Mode" after clicking control+h.